# Fix found_posts after changing query in pre_get_posts - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, posts

I am using a similar function to the following in order to hide out of stock products belonging to a specific category on the category/search result pages. Like so:

```
function hide_out_of_stock_parts_from_cat( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    if (is_product_category(1111) || is_search()){
        if ( $outofstock_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility' ) ) {

            $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

            $tax_query[] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms' => array( $outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'my-category-slug' ), 
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ),
            );

            $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        }

        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_parts_from_cat' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_parts_from_cat' );
```

This successfully removes the out of stock products belonging to "my-category-slug" from the category page and search results. However, the count of products being shown is wrong.

i.e) If the category had 5 products, but two were out of stock, there would only be three products shown. But, the found products message would say "showing all 5 products found" instead of 3.

I know this has something to do with "found_posts" but I'm not sure how to alter it.

Comment: found_posts should always apply to the whole query, including all extra restrictions you might have added. I would check the template where this is shown first of all, to verify that this is indeed taken from the same query.